# How to prevent ARKit app to place object if I click on the button (How to detect if I click on UI element)?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, arkit

How can I prevent ARKit app (initially made in Unity) from placing an object on the surface when I'm clicking on the UI button on the screen?

The solution from [this](https://youtu.be/S7kKQZuOdlk?t=7m56s) tutorial doesn't work:

```
if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(0))
```

Is there any other way to detect if I'm clicking on the UI element for IOS?

Here is the full code for placing objects using ARKit:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

namespace UnityEngine.XR.iOS
{
    public class UnityARHitTestExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform m_HitTransform;


        bool HitTestWithResultType (ARPoint point, ARHitTestResultType resultTypes)
        {
            List<ARHitTestResult> hitResults = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface ().HitTest (point, resultTypes);
            if (hitResults.Count > 0) {
                foreach (var hitResult in hitResults) {
                    Debug.Log ("Got hit!");
                    m_HitTransform.position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition (hitResult.worldTransform);
                    m_HitTransform.rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (hitResult.worldTransform);
                    Debug.Log (string.Format ("x:{0:0.######} y:{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0 && m_HitTransform != null)
            {
                var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(0))
                {
                    transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
                    var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
                    ARPoint point = new ARPoint {
                        x = screenPosition.x,
                        y = screenPosition.y
                    };

                    // prioritize reults types
                    ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
                        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 
                        // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
                        //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
                        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeHorizontalPlane, 
                        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
                    }; 

                    foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in resultTypes)
                    {
                        if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType))
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (noShoesPlaced) {
                    UIController.GetComponent<ShoeUIController2>().showShoe1
                    noShoesPlaced = false;
                }
            }

            //if (placeFirstTime) {
            //  UIController.GetComponent<ShoeUIController> ().firstTimePlace = true;
            //  placeFirstTime = false;
        //  }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Use the EventSystem for all your objects.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you, how definitely should I use EventSystem? I will try the method you describe in the answer to that question. Is it also applicable for IOS?

Comment: `EventSystem` should work on all platforms. Check the duplicate for examples depending on what type of object you want to detect clicks on.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you, If I understood your answer correctly, in case of buttons, this way I should assign buttons to variables, and then create functions which will be called when a particular button was clicked? So this is a way to assign functions to buttons in one script, instead of manually assign it to every button in the inspector, right? But I have a lot of buttons, Is there a way to detect if I click any object of button type (or any UI element as an option)? Finger click, not the mouse click.

Comment: @Programmer Also I wonder, why the method from the tutorial, which I posted above, doesn't work... I'm adding full ARKit code for object placing, in case if it can be helpfull.

Comment: I just saw your updated code and I suggest you create a new question with code. Also, I suggest you forget my first comment since this is AR stuff. You can also comment under that video since the uploader seems to be responding to people.